# Python not catching KeyboardInterrupt when stopping with code runner

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

When stoping the script with ctrl+alt+m python wont catch it as an interruption. I want to execute a cleanup script before exiting.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("keyboardInterrupt")

    finally:
        handle_cleanup()
```

How does code runner stop codes and what are my options to achive my goal?

Comment: Try using ctrl+c

Comment: Code runner does not support inputs, that I know of @JenilDave.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could just use the [`atexit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html) module:

```py
import atexit

def main ():
  atexit.register(handle_cleanup)
  ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: I tried what you said and it did not work with code runner but it did work with "vanilla" terminal.

Comment: You're right. Haven't tried testing on VSCode Code Runner. May I ask wheter VSCode Code Runner is really necessary?

Comment: It's actually not, but I prefer how clean it is. Does not show directroy and other stuff like that which a terminal would do.

Comment: If that's what you want, you could just `export PS1='> '` on terminal. That way, the prompt would be just `>`.

Comment: It seems like doing this kind of action using VSCode Code Runner [is not possible using the exit announcement from process](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/76284#issuecomment-506662963). The link I've attached has a Node workaround, but I don't know if Python has a similar one.